# D3 graph generate everytime access to the tab

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have added the D3 script to my web application which is developed by angularjs.
the D3 graph is drawn but multiple graphs are appear every time i access to the tabs.

Below is the script i used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        data = [{"value":200},
            {"value":100}];

        var w = 300,
        h = 300,
        r = 100,
        color = d3.scale.category20c();

        /*var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").data([data])
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
              .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")")*/

      var canvas = d3.select("body svg:svg");
        if(!svg){
    canvas = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg:svg").data([data])
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h)
                  .append("svg:g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")")
        }

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(r);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

        var arcs = canvas.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "slice");

        arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } )
            .attr("d", arc);

        arcs.append("svg:text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
            d.innerRadius = 0;
            d.outerRadius = r;
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d, i) { return data[i].value; });

    </script>
```

i added this script to the view that i wanted to show the graph.but after accessing to the specific tab the graph is show in every tab of my application.

[image]

As above image the grpagh is generated every time access to the tab/view.

can anyone help me this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you want to use unique element with id for your chart?

```
var canvas = d3.select("body svg:svg");
    if(!svg){
canvas = d3.select("body")
```

Try to change it to something like

```
var canvas = d3.select("#yourId svg:svg");
    if(!svg){
canvas = d3.select("#yourId")
```

Also add `<div id='yourId'></div>` tag to a tab, where your chart should be

Comment: Thanks a lot @Irina A.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing svg before rendering another svg

```
d3.select("svg").remove();
```